# Tibco AMX Business Studio BWSE service identification Issues after BC pallet installation

Tags: tibco, tibco-business-works

After Installing Business connect pallets for BW, I cannot see the Service related to BWSE component (Containing BC Pallets) in Service Grid Studio.
How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the 64 bit version of the AMX suit is installed int the C drive.
Try below step to resolve the issue:

```
C:\tibco\matrix64\dabs\1.5\tools\generateManifest\generateManifest.exe

C:\tibco\matrix64\studio\3.6\eclipse\TIBCOBusinessStudio.exe -clean
```